# Какие в JS есть решения хранения данных, которые доступных из любого места приложения?

Tags: javascript, localstorage, хранение-данных

Пишу скрипт на нативном JS, где нужные данные появляются в функции некоторого уровня вложенности, но должны быть доступными из любого уровня вложенности.

Среди моих познаний JS только один вариант реализации - хранить в localStorage.

То есть я помещаю данные в localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('answer', JSON.stringify(answer));
```

а потом забираю их оттуда:

```
localStorage.getItem("answer");
```

Говорят, localStorage синхронный, то есть останавливающий работу остальных скриптов пока сам выполняется. Наверняка есть ещё какие-то подводные камни. Мне даже не нужно хранить данные сессии; я их даже вынужденно удаляю при загрузке страницы. Более того меня не покидает чувство, что решение хранить промежуточные данные через localStorage - не изящное, и есть куда более профессиональное.

Есть возможность создать какое-то **хранилище** (массив, объект или ещё что-то), куда можно и записать, и считать данные, **не использую localStorage**? Например, данные появляются на 10-ом уровне вложенности, но доступны из любого места приложения?

ПС. Мне кажется, что решение прям очень простое, из азов JS, я прав?

Comment: О_о а просто объявить глобальную переменную в самом начале программы? `const ROOT = {};` — и добавлять туда что влезет. Также есть вариант прикрепить хранилище к глобальному объекту `window.ROOT = {};`

Comment: Оптиус прав, глобальная переменная решает проблему уровня вложенности. Локал сторадж нужен, скорее, для того, чтобы данные сохранялись между перезапусками программы - при закрытии страницы или вообще браузера

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, можете написать Ваше решение в ответ. Этим решением я и воспользовался

Comment: Главное не увлекайтесь этими глобалными переменными и стореджами. Можно сильно все запутать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если такой объект всего один, можно банально создать глобальную константу в самом начале программы и использовать его как связывающее звено между разными функциями. Скажем:

```js
const ROOT = {};

(function() {
  let colors = ["#b22", "#382", "#17a"];
  let i = 0;
  
  ROOT.next_color = function() {
    return colors[ i = (i + 1) % colors.length ];
  };
})();

(function() {
  document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = ROOT.next_color();
  });
})();
```

```html
« Клик »
```

При этом, если таких переменных станет многовато, это ничем не лучше использования обычных глобальных переменных. Захочется как-то группировать общие переменные в дополнительные вложенные объекты, чтобы случайно названия не пересекались.

Во время писанины мелкой браузерной игрушки, появилась необходимость пары десятка подобных объектов (классов). Везде таскать с собой "приставку" типа `ROOT.animate.add()`, `ROOT.battle` - не очень удобно. Как вариант - можно было в отдельном файле заранее глобально объявить все такие объекты, и уже в другом месте их заполнять.

Другой вариант (был принят как финальный), из каждой "папки" объявить свой глобальный объект через window. А чтобы не париться с вызовами функций, которые еще не созданы, сначала происходит объявление всех необходимых объектов и функций, а отдельная финальная функция управляет их запуском, около того:

```js
// файл
window.BUBU = {
  say: function(str) {
    alert(str);
    
    MOO.say("moo");
  },
};

// другой файл
window.MOO = {  // Если здесь объявить const MOO вместо window,
                // из BUBU он не будет виден, выдаст ошибку.
  i: 0,
  say: function(str) {
    alert(str);
    
    if (this.i++ < 4) BUBU.say("bubu");
  },
};

//***
BUBU.say("Начали!");
```

Такой подход как минимум работает, пока таких объектов - 10-20, для пары десятка тысяч строк кода. С бОльшими объемами не работал - не знаю)

Answer (score 5):

Думаю в Вашем случае подойдет глобальная переменная:

```js
window.STORAGE = {}

console.log(STORAGE)
// {}

STORAGE.data = 10101010

console.log(STORAGE)
// {
//   "data": 10101010
// }
```

В последней версии `ECMAScript` появилась возможность универсального обращения к глобальным объектам [glabalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis):

```
// браузер
window

// nodejs
global

// web-worker
self
```

Теперь мы можем удобно обращаться к нему, не беспокоясь о том что нужно менять `window` на `global` или `self`, если например нужно запустить скрипт на [Node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) или [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) соответственно:

```js
globalThis.STORAGE = {}

console.log(STORAGE)
// {}

STORAGE.data = 10101010

console.log(STORAGE)
// {
//   "data": 10101010
// }
```

Если нужно что более "серьезное", то стоит посмотреть в сторону [Redux](https://redux.js.org).